# pass dictionary key as a variable name does not work in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to use the "key" as variable name in dictionary.

```
>> print(port1)

2

>> print(virsh_out1)

{1: 'tap5be16f98-d3 bridge     qbr5be16f98-d3 virtio      fa:16:3e:0c:70:bf', 2: 'tap1685f051-29 bridge     qbr1685f051-29 virtio      fa:16:3e:b8:63:49', 3: 'tap54de7c68-a4 bridge     qbr54de7c68-a4 virtio      fa:16:3e:f5:c4:7a', 4: 'tap5b857c99-7c bridge     qbr5b857c99-7c virtio      fa:16:3e:a0:64:dc', 5: 'tap7104dac4-6b bridge     qbr7104dac4-6b virtio      fa:16:3e:fd:d3:ab', 6: 'tap0a3f7a0e-60 bridge     qbr0a3f7a0e-60 virtio      fa:16:3e:dd:50:35'}

>> dir(virsh_out1)

['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues']

>> print(virsh_out1[2])

tap1685f051-29 bridge     qbr1685f051-29 virtio      fa:16:3e:b8:63:49

>> print(virsh_out1[port1])

*** KeyError: '2'
```

Here, the value of variable name port1 = 2. If I try to use print(virsh_out1[port1]), it throws KeyError whereas the same thing works with print(virsh_out1[2]). Could someone please help?

Comment: port1 is a str, but you need an int

Comment: Thanks a lot. I converted it in into integer and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string `port1` into `int`,

```
port1 = '2'
virsh_out1 = {  1: 'tap5be16f98-d3 bridge     qbr5be16f98-d3 virtio      fa:16:3e:0c:70:bf', 
                2: 'tap1685f051-29 bridge     qbr1685f051-29 virtio      fa:16:3e:b8:63:49', 
                3: 'tap54de7c68-a4 bridge     qbr54de7c68-a4 virtio      fa:16:3e:f5:c4:7a', 
                4: 'tap5b857c99-7c bridge     qbr5b857c99-7c virtio      fa:16:3e:a0:64:dc', 
                5: 'tap7104dac4-6b bridge     qbr7104dac4-6b virtio      fa:16:3e:fd:d3:ab', 
                6: 'tap0a3f7a0e-60 bridge     qbr0a3f7a0e-60 virtio      fa:16:3e:dd:50:35'}

print(virsh_out1[int(port1)])
# tap1685f051-29 bridge     qbr1685f051-29 virtio      fa:16:3e:b8:63:49
```